Arithmetic interest of the Goss zeta function
I'm someone with more of a number fields background who recently started working on a project more in the function fields setting. I was reading Goss's book (Basic structures of function field arithmetic) and was perplexed at some of the function field analogues of familiar objects, especially the "function field analytic" Goss zeta function defined in chapter 8. The construction is fairly directly analogous, and its values seem to be related to the classical L-series values (8.12.5 in Goss). In a way, it seems to be very like a p-adic zeta function, with the key difference that completions of function fields do not embed into the complex numbers.
Certain elements in the project I'm considering appear related to a kind of "function field p-adic L-function," and I'm considering whether they're worth investigating. As such, I was wondering how much "has been done" with Goss zeta functions. Do they play any key role in function field arithmetic in the way p-adic zeta functions do in Iwasawa theory? Can you use them to prove things about classical L-functions, a la rank 1 BSD in the number field setting? I wasn't able to find much literature on them with a Google search, so I suspect the answer is no.
